# Vue2 error when trying to splice last element of object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 app wit a list of items which I can choose and show, or delete.

When deleting the last element in the list (and only the last one) - I get Vue warn - "[Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance: "

my HTML:

```
<body >
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list" v-on:click = "selectItem(index)" >
        <a>{{ item.name }}</a>
        <div v-on:click="deleteItem(index)">X</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
     <span>{{selectedItem.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</body>
```

The JS:

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        index: 0,
        selectedItem: {},
        list : [
            { id: 1, name: 'org1', desc: "description1"},
            { id: 2, name: 'org2', desc: "description2"},
            { id: 3, name: 'org3', desc: "description3"},
            { id: 4, name: 'org4', desc: "description4"}
        ]

      },

      methods: {
        deleteItem: function(index) {
           this.list.splice(index,1);
        },
        selectItem: function(index) {
            this.selectedItem = this.list[index];
       },
      }
    })
```

Can you please advise why does this happen and how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the use of this `<span>{{selectedItem.name}}</span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening as you have having `selectItem` bind at `li` level, so event when you click cross button, `selectItem` gets executed and that same item gets deleted as well, causing this error.

**One way** to solve this problem can be moving the `selectItem` binding inside `li` as follows

```
  <li v-for="(item, index) in list">
    <a v-on:click = "selectItem(index)" >{{ item.name }}</a>
    <div v-on:click="deleteItem(index)">X</div>
  </li>
```

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptja4cmy/).

**Another** approach can be when printing `selectedItem.name` in your HTML, you put a null check, whether `selectedItem` exist or not like following:

```
 <span>{{selectedItem && selectedItem.name}}</span>
```

See Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptja4cmy/1/).